# Exclude Included File From Cache Manifest

Tags: php, html, caching, local-storage

I'm a newbie to LocalStorage and am having some problems,

I have a form page in which includes two dynamic files

- The first file is repinfo.php and will echo "Hello ,$RepName"
- The second file is calculateEstimatedTime.php which echos "Estimated 241 minute wait"

Both of these files are display/included in swoapp.php. Since I want them to load dynamically I have put them to the network section of the Cache Manifest however they aren't loading/updating with new information and are just staying static.

```
CACHE MANIFEST


#version 20

CACHE:

swoapp.php

/app_framework/sisyphus.js

/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css

/js/jquery-1.11.0.js

/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js

/images/SWO-Header.png


NETWORK:

index.php

calculateEstimatedTime.php

repinfo.php

*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you include both php files on the server side. The client does not know that both of these strings were just included, they will be a static part of swoapp.php. For example, if your swoapp.php looks something like this

```
include("repinfo.php");
include("calculateEstimatedTime.php");
echo "Test";
```

the result will look like this:

```
Hello, $RepName
Estimated 241 minute wait
Test
```

The browser has no way of knowing that the first two lines are from included files, and so it will save it as if it all was static. When you want to have this loaded dynamically, you could for example use AJAX with XMLHttpRequests in order to load the content of repinfo.php and calculateEstimatedTime.php dynamically on the client side. Of course you then need to use JavaScript.

A simple AJAX tutorial is available at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP